# How to select value of textbox with radio button and linked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to run my code with the following logic below that is in the fiddle link.

1. Choose radio button
2. Click a link what you want
3. This link will be written in textbox of radio button

---

- When you choose radio button that was selected before, it can be changeable.
- There is a bug in my code. When you select a radio button after selecting another button and you select a link, this selected link is writing in 2 textbox of these selected radio button.

---

**JS Fiddle**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/johnvaldetine/ncxsajep/66/
```

**HTML**

```js
$('.bayi').on('change', function(e) {
  let hangi = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();
  console.log(hangi);
  if($('#d'+hangi).val().length > 0){
    // $('#d'+hangi).val(link);
    console.log('Zaten değer var.');
    console.log($('#d'+hangi).val());
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('Boş.')
    $('#secenekler a').click(
      function() {
        const link = $(this).attr('id');
        let tb = '#d'+hangi;
        console.log(tb);
        $(tb).val(link);
        tb = '';
        hangi = '';
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="secenekler">

<a id="ali" href="#">Ali</a> <a id="veli" href="#">Veli</a> <a id="mehmet" href="#">Mehmet</a> <a id="lorem" href="#">Lorem</a>
</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>



<form id="form">
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="1" > <input id="d1" type="text" ><br>
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="2"> <input id="d2" type="text"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="3"> <input id="d3" type="text">  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the click function inside radio button change function , check if any radio button is checked on click of the link.

```js
$('#secenekler a').click(function() {
 // get the id;
  const link = $(this).attr('id');
  // get checked radio button
  let k = $('input[name=bayi]:checked').val();
  // if any button is checked then update the value in input
  if (k !== undefined) {
    $('#d' + k).val(link)
  } else {
    console.log('Please select a radio button')
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="secenekler">

  <a id="ali" href="#">Ali</a> <a id="veli" href="#">Veli</a> <a id="mehmet" href="#">Mehmet</a> <a id="lorem" href="#">Lorem</a>
</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>



<form id="form">
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="1">
  <input id="d1" type="text"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="2">
  <input id="d2" type="text"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="3">
  <input id="d3" type="text">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems
1, you should not empty the `hangi` value and you should not bind the `a click` again and again

I have removed  `hangi = '';` so it is changeable as user wants.

I have moved  `$('#secenekler a').click(` outof change so it does not bind again and again.

hangi needs to be shared along with both so it should be on top.

Here the things I changed.

```js
let hangi = '';
$('.bayi').on('change', function(e) {


  hangi = $('input[type=radio]:checked').val();

  console.log(hangi);

  if ($('#d' + hangi).val().length > 0) {
    // $('#d'+hangi).val(link);
    console.log('Zaten değer var.');
    console.log($('#d' + hangi).val());
  } else {
    console.log('Boş.')

  }

});

$('#secenekler a').click(
  function() {
    const link = $(this).attr('id');
    let tb = '#d' + hangi;
    console.log(tb);
    $(tb).val(link);
    tb = '';


  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="secenekler">

  <a id="ali" href="#">Ali</a> <a id="veli" href="#">Veli</a> <a id="mehmet" href="#">Mehmet</a> <a id="lorem" href="#">Lorem</a>
</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>



<form id="form">
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="1"> <input id="d1" type="text"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="2"> <input id="d2" type="text"><br>
  <input type="radio" name="bayi" class="bayi" value="3"> <input id="d3" type="text">
</form>
```